# How could I create a horizontal UIPickerView style control?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview

[image: UIPickerView]

I want to create a custom UIView that would be equivalent to a horizontal UIPickerView. The data elements, such as "Mountain View, Sunnyvale, Cupertino, Santa Clara, San Jose" would move left to right. The view would be long and thin. 50px in height, 350x in width sort of thing.

I will need to use protocols to obtain my datasource elements likely, but what I'm more interested in figuring out is the visual aspect of this.

How would I animate things left and right? Should I just make one incredibly long view (off screen), and change the frame left and right. This seems like a bad idea, as likely only 3-5 options need to be visible in the control at one time. If the datasource is 100 elements, there is no point in loading the other 95 off screen in a long view.

So perhaps I should load ~9 or something. The 3-5 on screen, plus an additional ~3 left and right. Each time the control is triggered to move left and right, it will load up another element on the view(?).

Is this a good way to achieve this? A long thin view with ~9 UILabel's. As the control moves to the right, I would shift the further left UILabel to move hidden to the far right, and change the UILabel to be the next in the data source.

I also likely want to change the text size based on its position. If it's currently selected, I either want to bold it and possibly increase the font size. How can I gradually achieve this as the view is moved? It would be weird if the text only changed once it was moved perfectly center inside the view. It should likely gradually grow as it gets closer to the middle. 
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would look at the CollectionView. I find it very useful for horizontal image menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection view would do the trick, obviously there's some coding involved.
I'd suggest you to take a look at the code of, or use, the following library.
I've used it once,does almost exactly what you need and works very well:
[AKPickerView](https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView)

Comment: If that doesn't work for you, there is also this [carousel collection view](https://github.com/paweldudek/carousel-collection-view-layout) project which is a good example of how to build your own thing based off the collection view.